# Building a custom progress bar for Windows phone 8 App Using XAML and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a bar which decreases with time.

The xaml used is

```
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
      <TextBlock  Text="Timer :-" FontSize="35" Width="120" Height="70" Margin="138,167,222,531" ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="clock" FontSize="35" Width="100" Height="70" Margin="259,169,121,529" ></TextBlock>

    <Image x:Name="bar" Width="350" Height="20" Source="Assets/progress_bar_bg.png" Margin="65,271,65,477" ></Image>
    <Image x:Name="gbar"  Width="350" Height="20" Source="Assets/green_progress_bar.png" Margin="65,271,65,477" ></Image>

</Grid>
```

my c# code is

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Threading;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

    namespace PhoneApp1
    {
        public partial class ProgressBar : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        newTimer.Start();
        clock.Text = " 00:60";
    }

    DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    int counter = 60;

    int width = 350;
    double i=5.8;

    void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        counter--;

        if (counter < 0)
        {
            newTimer.Stop();
            counter = 60;
        }
        else
        {


                gbar.Width = width - i;

                clock.Text = " 00:" + counter.ToString();
                i=i+5.8;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have reduced the width such that the size of image green_progress_bar.png should decrease but the problem is that it is reducing from both the ends i want that it sholuld reduced from right to left as the time decrease from 60 sec to 0 sec. And the height is also decreasing with time i want image height to be fixed.

This is the image of what is happening in my case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want that the width of the bar should decrease from right to left.But it is decreasing from both the ends.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also note your when your times goes below 10 seconds it actually displays `00:9` instead of `00:09`...

Comment: Is using Images mandatory? Wouldn't it be easier to modify a style of Slider?

Comment: @mehow I have Corrected the issue pointed by you that when time goes below 10 seconds it actually displays 00:9 instead of 00:09

Comment: @Romasz Images are not mandatory, but i don't know much about Slider so i would be very happy if you help me out in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - it's going to be a long post. So first - the result:

[image: ProgressTimer]

I've changed a lot in your code (IMO some things might be improved). First of all - the style of the Slider (I've cut out most of the thing that weren't needed for your purpose. The complete template you can find at MSDN or by using Blend):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalFill" Fill="GreenYellow" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50">
                                <Rectangle.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 6, 12"/>
                                </Rectangle.Clip>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="HorizontalCenterElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="12" Margin="0,16,0,44" Width="12" Fill="GreenYellow">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>                            
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The most important things in the code above are: `HorizontalTrack`, `HorizontalFill` and `HorizontalCenterElement` - you can change the color, shape and so on. I've set centerelement as ellipse so it is a little rounded at the end. The best would be if you just play with it. Using the style goes like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="buttonStart" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Start" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="clock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ClockText}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Slider Name="gbar" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Value="{Binding ValueLeft, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Few things:

- I've changed content of UIElements and bound them to properties implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
- I've disabled Slider for hit testing - so the User won't be able to change it by touching

The rest of the code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaiseProperty(string property = null)
    { if (this.PropertyChanged != null)                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); }

    private TimeSpan timeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    public TimeSpan TimeLeft
    {
        get { return timeLeft; }
        set
        {
            timeLeft = value;
            RaiseProperty("ClockText");
            RaiseProperty("ValueLeft");
        }
    }

    public string ClockText { get { return timeLeft.ToString("m\\:ss"); } }

    public double ValueLeft { get { return TimeLeft.Ticks; } }

    private double maxValue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).Ticks;
    public double MaxValue // number of seconds
    {
        get { return maxValue; }
        set
        {
            TimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value);
            maxValue = TimeLeft.Ticks;
            RaiseProperty("MaxValue");
        }
    }

    System.Threading.Timer newTimer;
    private bool timerStarted = false;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        newTimer = new Timer(OnTimerTick);
        buttonStart.Click += buttonStart_Click;
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!timerStarted)
        {
            buttonStart.Content = "STOP";
            MaxValue = 60;
            timerStarted = true;
            newTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // start timer right now and invoke every second
        }
        else
        {
            buttonStart.Content = "Start";
            timerStarted = false;
            newTimer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite); // stop the timer
        }
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object state)
    { Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TimeLeft -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); }
}
```

Few things here:

- I've organized properties so that now when I change TimeLeft, the TextBlock and Slider are updated - Binding
- I've changed your DispatcherTimer to [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) - it runs on separate thread, and thus it won't block the UI (when there will be more calculations)
- because of that separate thread, the changes inside the Callback (on UI) will have to be proceeded via Dispatcher.

This example will surely work with `DispatcherTimer` fine when your interval is 1 second, but if you plan to perform some more calculations the second Timer may be a better choice. (It is only a different possibility).

Answer (score 2):

Set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` for both images. It is center by default.

Comment: it didn't work, still the width is decreasing from both sides.

Comment: height of green_progress_bar.png is also decreasing with time

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in image stretching, it can be disabled by `Stretch="None"`

```
<Image x:Name="gbar" Stretch="None" Width="350" Height="20" Source="Assets/green_progress_bar.png" />
```

Also try not to use `Margin` for exact positioning, `Grid` and `StackPanel` should help.

Instead of making your own progress bar I highly recommend to color/design Microsoft ProgressBar control, as we did it in http://highrobotics.com/we-did-it/wpf-themes.aspx

Comment: With Strech="None" the problem of height being reduced solved. But still the width is decreasing from both sides.

Comment: I know about the microsoft ProgressBar control, but i want to make something of this sort but thanks @Artru for your reply.

Comment: Then make HorizontalAlignment="Left" for the image (as Igor Kulman suggests) and remove Margins. This will align image to the left side of parent panel.